# How to refocus cursor to invalid input element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I have a page in which a set of text boxes are created based on number of items being shipped:

```
<c:forEach var="num" begin="1" end="${qtyToShip}" step="1" varStatus ="status">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input class="form-med" type="text" name="shipItems[${num - 1 }].barCode" id="shipItems[${num - 1 }].barCode" onchange="if(!G2Step2Validate(this,'${shippingCommand.boxType}')){$(this).focus();}" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input class="form-med" type="text" name="shipItems[${num - 1 }].shipCompanyBarCode"  onkeyup="if (!(event.keyCode==16 || (event.keyCode==9 && event.shiftKey))) {UPSStep2Validate(this);}"/>
    </td>
  </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Here is what I would like to happen.  When a user enters in a bar code, I need to make a AJAX call to validate that the bar code is valid (is available to be used, is correct for what is being shipped and has not already been used on this order - prevent duplicate scan).

Using DWR for AJAX and that service is all working fine.

The issue is that if the validation fails I would like the focus to return back to the field in question.  That is not happening.  The focus is always going to the next input box.

I have tried to work with different events: change, blur, keyup etc.  I have tried with placing the focus inline, in the javascript, have tried with jQuery, javascript etc but no luck.

Looking for suggestions/solutions on how to place the focus back to the input box that is causing the issue.

Comment: Have you tried calling the ".focus()" method of the DOM elements you want to get focus?  That's all you have to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of the nature of AJAX, the original approach is invalid.  That is

```
 <input class="form-med" type="text" name="shipItems[${num - 1 }].barCode" id="shipItems[${num - 1 }].barCode" onchange="if(!G2Step2Validate(this,'${shippingCommand.boxType}')){$(this).focus();}" />
```

can not be done.  The solution I came up with is this

```
 <input class="form-med" type="text" name="shipItems[${num - 1 }].barCode" id="shipItems[${num - 1 }].barCode" onchange="G2Step2Validate(this,'${shippingCommand.boxType}');" />
```

And then in the javascript function that is making the ajax call, if an error happens there then that has the control of setting focus.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the onblur even you will be able to set the focus. The issue is with timing and when the onchange event is fired.

```
<input class="form-med" type="text" name="shipItems[0].barCode" id="shipItems[0].barCode" onblur="if(true){this.focus();}" />
```

To make sure the cursor is at the end in IE you can add an onfocus event:

```
<input class="form-med" type="text" name="shipItems[0].barCode" id="shipItems[0].barCode" onblur="if(true){this.focus();}" onfocus="this.value = this.value;" />
```

Comment: The issue lies within the fact that I am making an ajax call.  So it appears that the focus has already changed by the time the ajax call has been completed.  So, making a call of this.focus() will not do the trick as 'this' has already been moved to the next dom object.

Comment: @boyd4715 sorry if G2Step2Validate contains an Async Ajax call you will have to set the focus from within the callback of that Ajax call. Since the first parameter of G2Step2Validate is this, assign it to a variable and call yourVariable.focus() from within the Ajax callback. If you provide the G2Step2Validate method body, I could help you further if need be.